# MD RAID 5 module doesn't load at boot

Tags: linux, mdadm, md

I recently upgraded my NAS to kernel 4.4 and now my md raid 5 array doesn't assemble itself at boot. `dmesg` reveals this: `[    2.299666] md: personality for level 5 is not loaded!` and doing `lsmod | grep raid` reveals that neither `md_mod` nor `raid456` is loaded. If I do `mdadm --stop /dev/md0` and then `mdadm --assemble /dev/md0` the array will successfully assemble and then doing `lsmod | grep raid` again shows all the required modules loaded. I've tried doing `mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0 4.4.0` with the array assembled and mounted but that doesn't seem to fix my issue. How can I make the module load at boot so my array assembles?

Comment: I fixed it by compiling the `raid456` module directly into the kernel.